# Hololens Sharing with Unet example: Client Hololens rotation and distance off by where I run the application in x or z axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, unity3d-unet

**Edit**

So I noticed that it is not bound to 90 degrees. It is basically wherever I start the app at. If I start the application on opposite walls it is off by 180 degrees. I have also noticed even if I start on the same wall and if I start it on the opposite side of the room they are off by that distance.

---

I am working with the Sharing with Unet example and I have modified it slightly to just spawn a capsule over the network similarly to the bullets. However, I have this weird thing that happens on the HoloLens that doesn't happen in the editor. The client HoloLens view is off by 90 degrees in the x or z axis I can't really tell which one. However the y axis is still in sync.

So I have 2 HoloLens and a computer that connects via a Network Manager HUD. I have no problems joining the session or anything but, for some reason the rotation of the 2nd (client)HoloLens is off. When looking through the scene view on the computer the host and computer client are in sync. However, when I move the capsule with the Holo client the scene view shows that it is looking in a different direction and the capsule is to the left of the Holo client.

Has anyone else had any luck with this? Any insight to this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding a command in the object controller that set its position based off of the inverse transform point of the shared world anchor when someone gained authority over the object. Looks something like this:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (receivedAuthority)
    {
        Vector3 objDir = transform.forward;
        Vector3 objPos = transform.position + objDir * .01f;

        localPosition = sharedAnchorTrans.InverseTransformPoint(objPos);

            CmdTransform(localPosition);           
    }

   else if(!receivedAuthority)
    {

         transform.localPosition = localPosition;

    }
}

[Command]
public void CmdTransform(Vector3 position)
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
      localPosition = position;
    }
}
```